# Unity Beginner - Tap / Click fires more then once

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a quad object with a png graphic as a child object.

This area is the tap / click area.

I attached a script to the object and it has the code:

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        bool tapped = Input.GetButton("Fire1");

        if (tapped){

            Debug.Log ("diram");

        }

    }
```

Problem is, on click in the test it fires twice, not once on click.

What do I do wrong here? I dont want a function to be called twice in tap or click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.GetButton` returns true when you hold down the button. You should use [Input.GetButton[Down|Up]](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html). Those methods return true respectively in the first frame the button is pressed or release.

Consider also read input events inside `Update` rather than `FixedUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay the shot you could also add a timer and another variable:

```
    public float delay; //change this in the Inspector
    public bool canshoot = true;

    private void Start()
    { 
      bool input = Input.GetButton("Fire 1");
      if(input && canshoot){
         canshoot=false;
         Shoot() // your shooting function)
         StartCoroutine(Reset(delay));
        }
    }


   IEnumerator Reset(float time){
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealTime(time);
    canshoot = true;
    }
```

Hope that helped!